# Use printer via terminal

Tags: printing, xerox

So, I'm pretty new to Ubuntu and basically I'm trying to use a printer via the Ubuntu termial, but I don't know how to do that.

I found on the web some commands that could do the job but I don't know how to configure the printer.

For example this one:

```
lp -d PRINTER_NAME PDF_FILES
```

I think I must need to install the drivers or something but I'm not sure if it works as in Windows or not.

Can anyone help me?

Just for the record, the printer is a Xerox.

Comment: Is the printer installed? Can you print from the GUI?

Comment: Try to find out the printer name first, and then test print a simple txt file. If that works, you already have necessary drivers.  To find out the name you could use `lsusb` if you're connecting through usb

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, but I already managed to make it work. It is actualy really easy.

Answer (score 1):

It was much easier than I thought. I just had to search for "Printers" in the Ubuntu dash, clicked "Add", searched for network printers, clicked on mine, and voila. That's pretty much it.

Then I just used the following command and everything worked great:

```
lp -d PRINTER_NAME PDF_FILES
```

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** Use your default printer with:

```
lp filename
```

---

*To specify a default printer or use specific printer, list all printers with*

```
lpstat -p -d
```

eg:

```
% lpstat -p -d
printer HP-LaserJet-1200 is idle.  enabled since Sa 06 Jun 2015 20:26:19 CEST
printer HP_Color_LaserJet_CP1514n is idle.  enabled since Do 21 Mai 2015 21:02:54 CEST
printer HP_LaserJet_1200 is idle.  enabled since Sa 30 Mai 2015 18:53:31 CEST
system default destination: HP_LaserJet_1200
```

*Print with*

```
lp -d printer filename
```

eg:

```
lp -d HP_LaserJet_1200 mypdf.pdf
```

*Set a default printer*

```
lpoptions -d printer
```

eg:

```
lpoptions -d HP_Color_LaserJet_CP1514n
```